# Mesh generation algorithm

Tags: algorithm

As part of a project I'm working on, I need to generate a 2D triangular mesh.

At the minute, I've implemented a Delaunay triangulation algorithm. I have to input a set of vertices, and it triangulates between them, and that works out great.

However, I'd like to improve on this and instead input a set of vertices that represent the edge of an arbitrary 2D shape (with no holes), and generate a (as uniformly as possible) mesh inside that shape, with varying degrees of precision (target number of triangles).

My Google skills seem to be lacking today, and I haven't found quite what I'm looking for.

Does anyone know of an algorithm / library / concept that will set me on my way?

Comment: so what's the difference between the stuff you already have and the stuff you want? The size of the triangles?...

Comment: Kind of, yes. With what I have now, I am able to generate set of triangles from any given set of vertices. What I want, is to give much fewer vertices, and the triangles be formed uniformly within. After searching some more, it seems that this, is what I'm after: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/tripaper/triangle3.html. My current algorithm gives me something like Figure 8. I want Figure 9.

Comment: So it is still a triangulation, just with a different constraint, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangles of the possibly non-convex 2D shape must not cross the border edges, a Constrained Delaunay triangulation can achieve that.

One solution: Triangulate with Fade [1] and insert the edges of the polygon. A uniform mesh inside the area can then be created using Delaunay Refinement.

[1] http://www.geom.at/fade2d/html/

hth